# Updating form choice field based on another choice field

Tags: column, update

I have a document library with two lookup columns. Column A is "Region" with the following choices:

- North
- South
- East
- West

Users can select more than one region when uploading a document.

Field B is "States" with the following choices:

- Florida
- Georgia
- California
- Washington
- North Carolina
- South Carolina

I am trying to add JavaScript to the newform.aspx and editform.aspx pages that will automatically add the corresponding states after a region is selected. Example:

User adds "South" as a choice in the "Region" field. "Florida" and "Georgia" are automatically added to the "States" field.

Logically, I imagine it to read like this:

if value of Region contains "South" {
        value of "States" = " + Florida + Georgia"
}

Clearly, I am not familiar enough with JavaScript or the CSOM to know how to write a statement that will update field B based on choices selected by the user in field A. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: these are called Cascaded columns and you can google for this term to find answers

Comment: I am familiar with cascading columns, but that is not the solution I am looking for. I want the values in the second column to automatically be selected, not just available based on the first column. Does that help clarify? Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

did you think about workflow that will put values you want to the second field?
Exp. If South is chosen, update item/set field status at the States field to Georgia
elseif west set field status States to California, and so on..

Comment: I have, but I would really like to do this with JavaScript on the form page. If I use a workflow, the user won't know the states were added until after they submit the doc to the doc library. I would like them to be able to see the changes on the form before they submit. Not to mention, I want to give them the option to remove some of the "States" that were automatically added, if they don't need all of them...I appreciate the suggestion, though!

Comment: its clear now :) sorry for misleading with an answer.